# How to post record in SQL using Ajax no page refreshing in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to post a record in SQL using Ajax without using a form but I have trouble:

> method not allowed

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="  2" />
<input type="text" value="detail" />
<input type="hidden" name="_Token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Submit Comment" />
```

Here is my controller:

```php
class Cdesigination extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $insertData = array(
            "name"      =>  Input::get("name"),
            "detail"    =>  Input::get("detail"),
            "token_key" =>  Input::get("_token")
        );

        return view('company');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        $record = array(
            "p_name"      =>  Input::get("name"),
            "p_price" =>  Input::get("price"),
            "p_detail"  =>  Input::get("detail")
        ); 

        return view('product');
    }
}
```

The route is:

```php
Route::post('add', ['as' => 'addrecord', 'uses' => 'Cdesigination@index']);
```

Ajax Function:

```js
function add()
{
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var detail = $('#detail').val();
    var token = $('#_token').val();

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '{{url("/posts")}}', 
        data: "name=" + name + "&detail=" + detail + "&_token=" + token,
        success: function(data){ } 
    }); 
}
```

Where is my mistake? Please guide me and explain how to post record in Laravel without using a form.

Comment: Where's your ajax code?

Comment: here is my ajax function                                                                                                        function add(){

   var name=$('#name').val();
   var detail=$('#detail').val(); 
   var token=$('#_token').val();
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{url("/posts")}}',
                    data: "name="+ name + "&detail="+ detail+"&_token="+ token ,
                    success: function(data){ 

                    }  });
}

Comment: Try update your question with ajax code.This is hardly readable. Btw where is /posts defined in your route.php? it should be url: '{{url("/your-route-to-product-function")}}',

Comment: Change the url posts to add first, by the way You should post the JS code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your url is: {url("/posts")} and you haven't this route defined

Comment: Route::post('addproduct', ['as' => 'posts', 'uses' => 'Cdesigination@product']); another route for product method this method have truble method not allowed